# How to stick widgets to dialog edges

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qdialog

How to make `lineedit` stick to the top and `button` to the lower edge of the dialog when it gets resized?

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout().insertLayout(0, layout)
        lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(lineedit)

        button = QPushButton(self)
        button.setText('ok')
        self.layout().addWidget(button)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(list())
dialog = Dialog()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a vertical spacer to the layout:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout().insertLayout(0, layout)
        lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(lineedit)

        # version (1): add vertical, expanding spacer item
        self.layout().addItem(
            QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding))

        # version (2): use "addStretch"
        # self.layout().addStretch()

        button = QPushButton(self)
        button.setText('ok')
        self.layout().addWidget(button)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(list())
dialog = Dialog()
app.exec_()
```

A `QSpacerItem` is just an unstyled, blank space, that consumes horizontal and vertical space in the layout according to its size policies.

`QSpacerItem`'s parameters:

- `w` - preferred width, `0`
- `h` - preferred height, `0`
- `hPolicy` - horizontal size policy, `QSizePolicy.Minimum` => the preferred width is sufficient, the item will not expand horizontally
- `vPolicy` - vertical size policy, `QSizePolicy.Expanding` => the item can make use of extra space, and thus will expand vertically and take all available space

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html#QSpacerItem and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum for details.

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if you would explain what `QSizePolicy.Minimum` and `QSizePolicy.Expanding` are. And how they change `QSpacerItem` appearance.

Comment: I added some explanations about `QSpacerItem`'s parameters and added links to the relevant Qt5 documentation pages.